# How can I display a negative mode preview with CameraX in Android?

Tags: android, android-camerax

I'm learning CameraX API, and [CameraXBasic](https://github.com/android/camera-samples/tree/master/CameraXBasic) is a office sample code.

*CameraFragment.kt* in *CameraXBasic* project displays a real camera preview.

Now I hope to display a negative mode preview.  How can I do with CameraX API? Is there a sample code?

**CameraFragment.kt**

```
private lateinit var viewFinder: TextureView

private fun bindCameraUseCases() {
    // Get screen metrics used to setup camera for full screen resolution
    val metrics = DisplayMetrics().also { viewFinder.display.getRealMetrics(it) }
    val screenAspectRatio = Rational(metrics.widthPixels, metrics.heightPixels)
    Log.d(TAG, "Screen metrics: ${metrics.widthPixels} x ${metrics.heightPixels}")

    // Set up the view finder use case to display camera preview
    val viewFinderConfig = PreviewConfig.Builder().apply {
        setLensFacing(lensFacing)
        // We request aspect ratio but no resolution to let CameraX optimize our use cases
        setTargetAspectRatio(screenAspectRatio)
        // Set initial target rotation, we will have to call this again if rotation changes
        // during the lifecycle of this use case
        setTargetRotation(viewFinder.display.rotation)
    }.build()

    // Use the auto-fit preview builder to automatically handle size and orientation changes
    preview = AutoFitPreviewBuilder.build(viewFinderConfig, viewFinder)

 ....

 CameraX.bindToLifecycle(
            viewLifecycleOwner, preview, imageCapture, imageAnalyzer)
}
```

Comment: What's a `negative mode`?

Comment: You can use `RenderScript` to achieve that. 1. How to use RenderScript with cameraX https://gist.github.com/LiewJunTung/b9b7f8444037fbcbe5b30a915850d494 2. RenderScript negative effect https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/effect/EffectFactory.html#EFFECT_NEGATIVE

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is an [`android.media.effect.Effect`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/android/media/effect/Effect.html) being applied to the `SurfaceTexture` (the `PreviewConfig` does not have any such properties). See [EffectFactory.EFFECT_NEGATIVE](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/android/media/effect/EffectFactory.html):

```
/**
 * Applies negative film effect on image.<br/>
 * Parameters: scale (float): the degree of film grain.
**/
public final static String EFFECT_NEGATIVE = "android.media.effect.effects.NegativeEffect";
```

[Here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/effect/package-summary) it is also explained (the Kotlin and Java documentation are differently organized).

However, you might need to use your own `SurfaceTexture`, because it else it is difficult to get the GLContext. This example is almost working, but the `texture.attachToGLContext()`:

```
private EffectContext fxContext = null;
private EffectFactory fxFactory = null;
private Effect fx = null;

protected void applyNegativeEffect(SurfaceTexture texture, int width, int height) {
    if(this.fxContext == null) {
        // texture.attachToGLContext(texture.mSurfaceTexture);
        this.fxContext = EffectContext.createWithCurrentGlContext();
    }
    if(this.fxFactory == null) {
        this.fxFactory = this.fxContext.getFactory();
    }
    if(this.fx == null) {
        this.fx = fxFactory.createEffect(EffectFactory.EFFECT_NEGATIVE);
        this.fx.setParameter("scale", 1.0f);
        // this.fx.apply(0, width, height, 0);
    }
}
```

But `SurfaceTexture` (where `long mSurfaceTexture` would need to be exposed) reads:

```
/**
 * These fields are used by native code, do not access or modify.
**/
private long mSurfaceTexture;
```

---

Setting a shader on a `GLSurfaceView` might be easier to accomplish:

```
String shader = "#extension GL_OES_EGL_image_external : require\n"
    + "precision mediump float;\n"
    + "varying vec2 vTextureCoord;\n"
    + "uniform samplerExternalOES sTexture;\n"
    + "void main() {\n"
    + "  vec4 color = texture2D(sTexture, vTextureCoord);\n"
    + "  float colorR = (1.0 - color.r) / 1.0;\n"
    + "  float colorG = (1.0 - color.g) / 1.0;\n"
    + "  float colorB = (1.0 - color.b) / 1.0;\n"
    + "  gl_FragColor = vec4(colorR, colorG, colorB, color.a);\n"
    + "}\n";
```

And a camera2 [example](https://www.maninara.com/2015/03/render-camera-preview-using-opengl-es.html) for OpenGL ES preview.

Getting the GLContext from CameraX abstraction is the actual problem, because one would need to build [androidx.camera.core](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/fe4b6d14c2d6cd430a335628871eb2abf40fd82a/camera/core/src/main/java/androidx/camera/core) with a custom OpenGL preview, in order to apply the shader - or to get the input/ouput `texId`.

**Update**:

[Implement a preview](https://developer.android.com/training/camerax/preview) reads:

> If you require direct access to the `SurfaceTexture`, such as to perform OpenGL rendering, see [Manually create a SurfaceTexture](https://developer.android.com/training/camerax/preview#kotlin). In these cases, pass in a `SurfaceTexture` to a `Preview` object using `Preview.PreviewSurfaceProvider`.

See issue issue [#146957342](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/146957342), `Futures.immediateFuture(surface)` doesn't work anymore.

Comment: Thanks!   Do you mean that it's a little difficult to display a negative mode preview with CameraX in Android because  we can't get the GLContext from CameraX ?